# Reset random generator Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, random

i am creating an app, that in the class i have this random:

```
public class Ejemplo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 int ran=(int)(1*Math.random()) +1;
```

and also have this counter

```
int contador= 0; // this is just to know how many time i won
```

then i have 2 buttons a1 and a2

and in my onClick

```
     switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.a1:
        if(ran == 1){
            a1.setText("WIN");
            contador= contador + 1;
        }
        else{
            a1.setText("0");
        }
        a1.setClickable(false);
        break;

    case R.id.a2:
        if(ran == 2){
        a2.setText("WIN");
        contador= contador + 1;
        }

        else{
            a2.setText("0");
        }
        a2.setClickable(false);
        break;
```

so the problem is that when i press the button: New Game the random is going to have the same number of the random, and i cant just call again the activity bc i dont want to reset my counter: contador.

How i can just reset my random, so it doesnt always select the same button?

Answer (score 2):

just use a `Random` instead of `Math.random` it's easier to use, you can have like this:

```
Random random = new Random(); // random generator

// then inside your onClick this code
if(random.nextBoolean()){
   // win
} else {
   // lose
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html

**edit:**

it's really much simpler than what you trying to do:

```
public class Ejemplo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   Random random = new Random(); // random generator




   // then inside the click listener:
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.a1:
        if(random.nextBoolean()){
           a1.setText("WIN");
           contador= contador + 1;
           gano();
          }
          else{
             a1.setText("0");
          }
          a1.setClickable(false);
          break;
```

Comment: i will try thx, but where in the code i have to put that? i can have Random random = new Random(); in where i have my int ran=(int)(1*Math.random()) +1; and the if in the switch?

Comment: yes. The `Random` replaces the `int` and the `if-else` replaces the `switch`

Comment: thx but i cant, i try this in github, if u have the chance to look at it, it will be great: https://github.com/Aqwe123/Problem-with-reset-random-Android-

Comment: the problem of that is that there are not just 2 buttons(i put here just two to be more quickly), so i have to put a rank.

Answer (score 0):

Put `int ran=(int)(1*Math.random()) +1;` in the `onClick` rather than declaring it as an instance variable in the activity. So everytime a click happens, your `ran` variable will have a different value.

Comment: i cant do that, bc the idea of the game is that you have two choices and 1 of them is the WIN, and if i have that in that swith maybe no one wins. then also i cant click two times one buttom, just ones